# Multi-uploads with Carrierwave on Rails 4.2 using nested attributes JSON/Array type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to figure out multi-uploads with CarrierWave and being able to save it from a different Controller and Model through `accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true`

I'm using CarrierWave and my `CarImage` model contains a JSON type column for the image.

When creating a new car post `CarsController#New` I want to be able to:

- Write title *(working)*
- Write description *(working)*
- Upload multiple images through nested forms *(working)*

I get the following error message when trying to save a new Car with images attached:

`Unpermitted parameter: images`

The params:

```
Started POST "/cars" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-20 22:04:19 +1000
Processing by CarsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GEAGEAKQw3foK7/1+kGMhTVArqRaC8gHaHjHAtef0zmJDr2i5U9TictQ9kj3A==", "car"=>{"title"=>"Ford", "description"=>"Mustang", "car_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbec0dfa5a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/r0/24wrt39d1kl37mmymjjmmxy45000gn/T/RackMultipart20150820-12757-1e4egob.jpg>, @original_filename="ford-mustang-front.jpg", @content_type="image/jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"car[car_images_attributes][0][images][]\"; filename=\"ford-mustang-front.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbec0dfa508 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/r0/24wrt39d1kl37mmymjjmmxy45000gn/T/RackMultipart20150820-12757-6pckqd.png>, @original_filename="ford-mustang-back.jpg", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"car[car_images_attributes][0][images][]\"; filename=\"ford-mustang-back.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n">]}}}, "commit"=>"Create Car"}
```

I'm not sure if it's to do with the form, but when saving multiple files as an Array should it have unique indexes? The params log looks like it's saving all the images in the first index: `car[car_images_attributes][0][images][]\`

My `CarsController` the permits the following params:

```
    def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:title, :description, 
      car_images_attributes: [:id, :car_id, :image])
    end
```

The `car_images_attributes` permits the `:image` attribute which is a JSON/Array type.

Any insight is much appreciated.

---

#### Car Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: cars
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  title       :string           default(""), not null
#  description :text             default("")
#  price       :float            default(0.0)
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null


class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

#### Car Image Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: car_images
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  image       :json             default({}), not null
#  title       :string           default(""), not null
#  car_id      :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class CarImages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

#### Car Controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @car = Car.new
    @car.car_images.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save    
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        @car.car_images.build # ensures car_image form object exists

        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Car was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_car
      @car = Car.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end

    def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:title, :description, car_images_attributes: [:id, :car_id, :images])
    end
end
```

#### Car Form

---

```
<%= simple_form_for @car, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :title  %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :car_images do |image| %>
    <% if image.object.new_record? %>
      <%= image.input :images, as: :file, required: false, error: false, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Any insights is much appreciated.

I was thinking of iterating through the params[:car_images]['image'] and creating a CarImage record, but i thought this might not be the best way, and would want to be able to add a Car record without images, and this would fail if it doesn't have an image attached unless extra checks (nil) is done.

### Update

I've tried DB column types `JSON` and `TEXT (as an array)` but still have the problems. If I change it as a plain `STRING` it works but it's not a collection of photos.